# jQuery: how to get param from html element added with .append and handled with .on?

Tags: jquery, events, parameters, delegates, click

I use the now classic ".on" jquery handler for checking the click on some anchor I added with append.

```
$('#selector-to-thing-that-exists').on('click', '.thing-that-will-be-added-later', function() {
  //I want to get the "data-pointnumber" and "data-goodanswer" on the clicked element.
});
```

The problem here is that $(this) give me the $('#selector-to-thing-that-exists') and not the clicked element (it's a link).
Am I clear enough?

```
$.each(this.currentQuestion.Reponse,function (arrayID,rep) {
    $('#QuestionContainerSingle').find('.liste-boutons').append('<li><a href="" class="button-big btn-rep" data-nbpoints="'+rep.NbPoints+'" data-bonne="'+rep.Bonne+'">'+rep.Texte+'</a></li>');
});
$('#QuestionContainerSingle').on('click','.btn-rep',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('data-nbpoints'));
});
```

Here is the html... As it is part of a bigger application it's not easy to extract just what I need for this question!

```
<div class="question-content" id="QuestionContainerSingle">
            <div class="header-question">
                <p class="intitule">

                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title-box">Find the best answer</div>
                <ul class="liste-boutons">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: $(this) would give you the class '.thing-that-will-be-added-later', not #selector-to-thing-that-exists. The extra parameter passed between click and function() is basically to the target element inside #selector-to-thing-that-exists. Also, if you could add the html, it would help in figuring out the exact problem

Comment: I edited my question with some html and changing a little bit my JS to be clearer... I still do not understand why $(this) do not return me the ".btn-rep" clicked element. Just note that "e.target" return me the good element!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the culprit! I use this.btnRep = $('.btn-rep'); in the init of my app.
When I use

```
$('#QuestionContainerSingle').on('click',**this.btnRep**,function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('data-nbpoints'));
});
```

it's not working.
But when I use

```
$('#QuestionContainerSingle').on('click',**'.btn-rep'**,function (e)
```

it's working...
Stange!

Comment: The reason why its not working in the 1st case is because you are passing an object inside your selector. jquery selectors only works with string values, not objects